# How to integrate an Angular component in React remote using ModuleFederation

Tags: reactjs, angular, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I have the following structure:

```
-mfp/
 - react-host/
  - webpack.dev.js
  - index.js
  - bootstrp.js
  - src/
   - App.js
 - angular-remote/
  - webpack.config.js
  - src/
   - main.ts
   - bootstrp.ts
   - app/
    - app.module.ts
```

my `webpack.config.js` in my angular-remote look the following

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');


module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "ang",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:8082/"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: 'var', name: 'ang' },
        name: "ang",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
            './angApp': './src/app/app.component.ts',
        },        
      
        shared: {
          '@angular/core': { eager: true, singleton: true },
          '@angular/common': { eager: true, singleton: true },
          '@angular/router': { eager: true, singleton: true },
        },
    }),
  ],
};
```

My `webpack.dev.js` in my react-remote look the following

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
const packageJson = require('../package.json');

module.exports = = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    historyApiFallback: {
      index: 'index.html',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'marketing',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './MarketingApp': './src/bootstrap',
      },
      shared: packageJson.dependencies,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

My `app.module.ts` is the following:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  // bootstrap: []

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Still I don't see my angular app in my react, I can import in my react-host `App.js` the following

```
import angApp from 'ang/angApp'
```

without any error,I even see at the network tab in the console the call's to the JS return successfully  but nothing appears.

Answer (score 6):

I found a wonderful [git repo](https://github.com/harshmons/micro-front-end-react-application.git) that implements exactly what I intended to do. if any one come across this issue, worth checking it out.